# enum values in a class - Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, enums

I made a functions class that contains enumerated values but when called in my main.cpp, I get a "has not been declared" error. I'm trying to figure out where I'm going wrong but not having much luck. My class header, currently (reduced to fit here):

```
class main_funcs : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
main_funcs(QObject *parent, QQuickView *view)
    : QObject(parent), myDialog(view){

    IP_is_set = false;
    newIP = null;
    newIP.resize(50);
    local_IPv4 = null;

    enum direction {up, down};
    enum sys_sides {left, right};
    enum sys_control {analog, digital};
public slots:
    void myfunc1();
    void myfunc2(sys_sides side);
    void myfunc3(direction dir);
    void myfunc4(sys_control type);
private:
    ...
    ...
}
```

and in my main.cpp, I'm connecting signals to slots:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    // MAIN CONTROL WINDOW:
    QQuickView* view = new QQuickView(QUrl("main.qml")); 
    view->show();
    QQuickItem *rect = view->rootObject();
    main_funcs *funcs = new main_funcs(0, view);

    QObject::connect(rect, SIGNAL(onClicked_func1()), funcs, SLOT(myfunc1()));
    QObject::connect(rect, SIGNAL(onClicked_func2()), funcs, SLOT(myfunc2(funcs::up)));
    QObject::connect(rect, SIGNAL(onClicked_func3()), funcs, SLOT(myfunc3(funcs::left)));
    QObject::connect(rect, SIGNAL(onClicked_func4()), funcs, SLOT(myfunc4(funcs::analog)));
```

The error appears in the class header at the functions that require enumerated values. The error is that the enumerated value "has not been declared"  -It's declared in the public heading just above it. I'm still a C/C++ newb, and definitely new to Qt as I haven't done much with it. Can anyone point me in the right direction at the very least? Thanks!

Comment: As pointed out by both answers you cannot put enum values in signal/slot declaration. You can however put enum types. You could use the `Q_ENUM` macro to explose the enum to qml. That should simplify your problem.

Comment: There is something strange in your code, I cannot see the closing curly bracket of your constructor main_funcs. If the closing bracket in the real file is right before "public slots": then this is way your enums do not work, it's because they are local to your constructor

Comment: @FélixCantournet You could also use a lambda... but that generally means you didn't plan your signal out properly.

Comment: @Marco - just a typo in this post, the closing bracket is present in my code closing the `main_funcs(QObject *parent...` constructor. I'll try moving the enum values again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your call to your `enum`s is wrong. They are scoped by the class, not the class object.

Try this:

```
QObject::connect(rect, SIGNAL(onClicked_func2()), funcs, SLOT(myfunc2(main_funcs::up)));
QObject::connect(rect, SIGNAL(onClicked_func3()), funcs, SLOT(myfunc3(main_funcs::left)));
QObject::connect(rect, SIGNAL(onClicked_func4()), funcs, SLOT(myfunc4(main_funcs::analog)));
```

**EDIT:**
That'll solve the "has not been declared" error, but I realize that you'll then get another error. You're trying to pass arguments into a function pointer, that won't work.

A signal will take an argument, the parameter that you pass in there will be passed, by Qt, to your slot. *You do not control the arguments to your slot in the connection. You control your arguments to the slot by what you pass to the signal.*

Read through this for more info: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html

Comment: Thanks - I think I found my problem - as you and @Marco pointed out, my enum statements were in the wrong place in the class object. I moved them outside the QObject  constructor and left them under the public heading and all has compiled so far. I'll be testing later today to make sure they run. Thanks again!

Comment: @JediEngineer Just don't forget to look over the `connect` call. If you have more questions on that you should probably open a new question, but if you post the link here I'll come have a look.

Comment: @JediEngineer The code that I have there has an error in that the `SLOT`s are not actual functions, cause they have arguments in them. If you plug this code in I do *not* expect it to work.

Comment: are you saying that the slots that contain functions with arguments will not work in Qt?

Comment: @JediEngineer Yes, that is what I'm saying. [Qt states](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect): "Note that the signal and slots parameters must not contain any variable names, only the *type*."

Comment: how then (I'm still green) should I pass the argument into the function?  My compiler didn't complain once I fixed the enum problem.

Comment: the way I'm reading it is that I can't put the variable name in there, but the type is ok. if I just say `QObject::connect(rect, SIGNAL(onClicked_sys_myfunc()), funcs, SLOT(myfunc(bool)));` then that connection doesn't indicate whether or not the method should operate on the "true" case. In my example, I'm not passing a variable name, but an enumerated value or bool condition. My understanding is that it is not the same as a variable name. Shouldn't the compiler catch it when I build the program? Because it hasn't complained about it yet...

Comment: @JediEngineer The way that you *should* be passing arguments to your slot is by calling them in your signal. So in your example `onClicked_sys_myfunc` should have a `bool` parameter and you should call `rect->onClicked_sys_myfunc(true)` to signal `true`. Also in [this section](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html#signals-and-slots-with-default-arguments) of the link at the end of my answer you'll see that the `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros are *not* checked at compile time, only run time. If you don't understand everything after reading through the link I'd suggest you open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

There are some major issues with your code. You should not define values when connecting signal and slots. Only the types should be provided in the old style connecting syntax.

Also when connecting a signal to some slot, the signal should provide the arguments for the slots. So here you cal not connect any of the signals `onClicked_func2`,.. to the slots as they do not have any argument apparently. (In case `onClicked_func2` is really a signal, it looks like a slot)

Also if you want to use the enumeration types, you should use the enumeration in the class scope by following the class name like :

```
main_funcs::up
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suggest to put constructor definition in the cpp file, not in the class definition file, it will help keeping things tidy and not to forget closing curly brackets of the constructor like in this case.

Second I suggest also to keep your enums outside the class definition so you will be able to use them in other classes, as they seem to be very general logic enums.

Thirds signals and slots do not work that way, you need to connect SIGNAL signatures with identical slot signatures you cannot be passing actual parameters during connect I do not thing that will ever work, and you should be getting also a lot of connect errors during start up.